# Detect Whether Polygon is Clicked Inside or Outside the Radius

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h21gd1ce/), if you click on the larger polygon (along Tireman Ave), you will see that a radius is drawn around it.

1. The first problem is that the radius needs to be updated every time
   a new polygon is selected. I am not able to remove the previous
   radius.
2. I want to then determine whether the subsequent polygon a user
   clicks on is *inside* that radius or *outside*. If they click on a
   polygon that is inside the radius, I want to use `alert("Selected Polygon Inside Radius");` (and vice-versa).

---

This is the part I need help with:

```
polygons.forEach(function (polygon) {
    polygon.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function (event) {
        //alert("hello");
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0,
            map: map,
            clickable: false,
            center: event.latLng,
            radius: 500
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What if part of the polygon is inside the radius and part is outside?

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: If you click on another polygon, that moves the circle. I'm not sure what you mean by #2 ("I want to then determine whether the subsequent polygon a user clicks"), when they do that the circle moves, so the clicked polygon is always inside the circle.

Comment: @geocodezip I think what I was trying to get at is that the circle shouldn't move if I click on a polygon that is already inside the radius. Do you know what I mean? How can I achieve that? Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Maybe you need to clarify question #1 then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to part #1 of your question: Make the reference to the circle global.  If the circle exists and has a `setMap` method, hide the existing circle before overwriting it with the new one.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h21gd1ce/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 1,
    "properties": {
      "Name": "",
      "description": "",
      "timestamp": "",
      "begin": "",
      "end": "",
      "altitudeMode": "clampToGround",
      "tessellate": 1,
      "extrude": -1,
      "visibility": -1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [-83.126571, 42.348706],
          [-83.126520, 42.348634],
          [-83.126516, 42.348635],
          [-83.126147, 42.348778],
          [-83.126144, 42.348780],
          [-83.126195, 42.348852],
          [-83.126199, 42.348851],
          [-83.126568, 42.348708],
          [-83.126571, 42.348706]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 2,
    "properties": {
      "Name": "",
      "description": "",
      "timestamp": "",
      "begin": "",
      "end": "",
      "altitudeMode": "clampToGround",
      "tessellate": 1,
      "extrude": -1,
      "visibility": -1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [-83.132805, 42.356496],
          [-83.132753, 42.356423],
          [-83.132751, 42.356424],
          [-83.132243, 42.356624],
          [-83.132241, 42.356625],
          [-83.132294, 42.356698],
          [-83.132296, 42.356697],
          [-83.132802, 42.356497],
          [-83.132805, 42.356496]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 3,
    "properties": {
      "Name": "",
      "description": "",
      "timestamp": "",
      "begin": "",
      "end": "",
      "altitudeMode": "clampToGround",
      "tessellate": 1,
      "extrude": -1,
      "visibility": -1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [-83.126776, 42.351813],
          [-83.126492, 42.351413],
          [-83.126189, 42.351525],
          [-83.126191, 42.351528],
          [-83.126376, 42.351807],
          [-83.126776, 42.351813]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }]
};

var map;
var path = [];
var polygons = [];
var circle;

function initializeMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.35210605281608, -83.12983274459839),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  createGeoJsonPolygon(data);

}

function createGeoJsonPolygon(data) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var coords = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = data.features.length; i < len; i++) {
    coords = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0];

    for (var j = 0; j < coords.length; j++) {
      var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[j][1], coords[j][0]);
      bounds.extend(pt);
      path.push(pt);
    }
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      path: path,
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 1,
      fillOpacity: 0.5
    });
    polygons.push(polygon);
    path = [];

  }

  polygons.forEach(function(polygon) {
    polygon.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function(event) {
      //alert("hello");
      if (circle && circle.setMap) {
        circle.setMap(null);
      }
      circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0,
        map: map,
        clickable: false,
        center: event.latLng,
        radius: 500
      });
    });
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```